# Itemize within thmtool box

Tags: spacing, itemize, thmtools

So I got the following problem: If I want to use itemize within a thmtool-box without text (so only itemize within the box) there is a small gap between the header of the box and the itemize. It looks like this:

[image]

It can be recreated with the following Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[thmbox=M]{test}
\begin{document}
    \begin{test}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{test}
\end{document}
```

Can someone help be getting rid of that extra space? I got a lot of different named boxes designed using thmtools and I don't want to use \vspace{...} everytime.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enumitem` to customize the appearance of `itemize` lists:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[myitemize]{label=\textbullet,
                    font=\upshape,
                    before={\begin{minipage}{\hsize}}, 
                    after={\end{minipage}}
                   }
\declaretheorem[thmbox=M]{test}
\begin{document}
    \begin{test}
        \begin{myitemize}
            \item text
        \end{myitemize}
    \end{test}

\end{document}
```

---

You can also redefine the `itemize` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{label=\textbullet,
                  font=\upshape,
                  before={\begin{minipage}{\hsize}}, 
                  after={\end{minipage}}
                   }
\declaretheorem[thmbox=M]{test}
\begin{document}
    \begin{test}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item text
        \end{itemize}
    \end{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding `font=\upshape` to the options of enumitem would make the bullet look nicer, in my opinion.

Comment: So there is no possibility doing this without adding a new environment?